# Greek female name associated with gifts, a tool, a weapon, or a lie - must sound relatively 'normal' for a modern name

Tags: greek, names, goddesses, maiden-goddesses

I'm writing a story, and the beginning of the story has a woman in it that doesn't actually exist - she's a figment of some mental manipulation upon the protagonist by a magical Greek cult.

I've done some googling but couldn't find what I'm looking for - which is:

1. A name for this female character that doesn't sound *too* out of
   place for a modern name (there's definitely some leeway here)
2. Doesn't immediately jump out as "Yeah, that's definitely something
   greek/mythological"
3. And has some sort of connection plotwise with her role in the story.

Basically, the protagonist has had their memories tampered with, with the idea of turning them into an assassin of a government official.  The female character is a fake memory/creation to help "smooth over" the critical memories - giving the main protagonist a fake sounding board and a source of suggestions for courses of actions.  So anything along the lines of:

- Tool or Toolmaker
- Lies or Figment
- Artificial Creation
- Gift
- Two-Edged Sword
- Weapon
- etc

Any ideas for a female name that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you'd have to modernize an existing name to your purpose.
*(F) = Female
*(M) = Male

Hesiod, Theogony 211ff (trans. Evelyn White; Greek epic 8th or 7th century B.C.):[3]

And Nyx (F)(Night) bare hateful Moros (M)(Doom) and black Ker (F)(Violent Death) and Thanatos (M)(Death), and she bare Hypnos (M)(Sleep) and the tribe of Oneiroi(M)(Dreams). And again the goddess murky Nyx, though she lay with none, bare Momos (M)(Blame) and painful Oizys(F)(Misery), and the Hesperides(F) ... Also she bare the Moirai(F)(Fates) and the ruthless avenging Keres (F)(Death Fates) ... Also deadly Nyx bare Nemesis (F)(Envy) to afflict mortal men, and after her, Apate (F)(Deceit) and Philotes (F)(Friendship) and hateful Geras (M)(Old Age) and hardhearted Eris (F)(Strife).

Comment: Oooh - Eris looks perfect.  She's Strife/Chaos/Discord, she's the mother of Lethe (forgetfulness/oblivion) - and it's a name that wouldn't cause a double-take; it's not hard to imagine meeting a woman that happened to be named Eris, so hopefully the reader won't make a connection to greek pantheon when the subject of a greek cult comes up.  +1, and if nobody gives a better alternative, I'll mark it as accepted tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Best two-edged name I can think of is IEZABEL (Ἰεζάβελ): Greek form of Hebrew Iyzebel ("Ba'al exalts," "unchaste," or "without cohabitation"), but meaning "chaste, intact.". Modern-day form would be Isabelle.

Gift:

- CALLIDORA, composed of kallos "beauty" and doron "gift"
- EUDORA,  eu "good" and doron "gift"
- ISIDORA, "gift of Isis"

Other:

- RHEBEKKA, Greek form of Hebrew Ribqah, meaning "ensnarer.",
- KASSANDRA: meaning "she who entangles men."
- MEDEIA: meaning "cunning"
- PERSEPHONE: persô "person; human being" and phonos "murderer, slayer," hence "person-slayer."

Comment: I guess I was looking less for 'Etymology' and more 'Mythology'.  For instance, Kassandra.  That's less "she who entangles men" and more "seer who was cursed to see the future but never be believed".  And Persephone being the goddess who was married to Hades, not "murderer/slayer"